# Oculus Rift fails to load Firefox

Tags: firefox, oculus, webvr

I'm attempting to run WebVR content on Firefox within my Oculus Rift using the "Enter VR" button on the various examples at AFrame.io/MozVr.com. Before selecting the button I can see that my Rift is reacting with the visualization on the screen (it pans back and forth etc. as I turn the headset). However, when I click the "Enter VR" button, the home screen within the Oculus fades to black as though it will load Firefox, but then fades back to the Oculus home screen.

Unfortunately the Oculus doesn't share information about what is causing this error. I'm using the most recent versions of Oculus and Firefox (currently version 57), which I know for sure is WebVR compatible. I also confirmed that Firefox's about:config settings are set to enable Oculus.

Has anyone encountered this? Thanks.

Comment: I've confirmed this problem is happening on Firefox 57. Firefox 56 seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

So do I.
Though a makeshift way...

Leave VR , close Oculus Home and browser.
 Launch a browser and enter VR.
 If Oculus Home is launched automatically, the sample works well.

I hope you will go well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (gaming laptop):

go to NVIDIA control panel and select

Manage 3D Settings

Program settings

select Firefox

and pick "High-performance NVIDIA processor'

in the select the preferred graphics processor...
click Apply